# Apply element to successive elements in a List

Tags: scala

I'm looking for a way to apply each element in a List with its successive elements in Scala without writing a nested for loop. Basically I'm looking for a List comprehension that allows me to do the following:

Let 
`A = {a, b, c, d}`

Then `A' = {ab, ac, ad, bc, bd, cd}`

I thought about using `map` for example, `A.map(x => ...)`, but I can't figure out how the rest of the statement would look.

Hopefully this all makes sense. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you need all the combinations of the characters or only those you specified?

Comment: Only those I specified, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems a natural for a recursive evaluation. since it's prepend the first element to the rest of the list, then follow with the same thing applied to the rest of the list.

```
def pairs(xs: List[Char]): List[String] = xs match {
  case Nil | _ :: Nil => Nil
  case y :: ys        => ys.map(z => s"$y$z") ::: pairs(ys)
}

pairs(a) //> res0: List[String] = List(ab, ac, ad, bc, bd, cd)
```

Tail recursive

```
def pairs2(xs: List[Char], acc:List[String]): List[String] = xs match {
  case Nil | _ :: Nil => acc.reverse
  case y :: ys        => pairs2(ys, ys.foldLeft(acc){(acc, z) => s"$y$z"::acc})
}

pairs2(a, Nil)  //> res0: List[String] = List(ab, ac, ad, bc, bd, cd)
```

Or if you really want a comprehension:

```
val res = for {(x::xs) <- a.tails
                y <- xs
              } 
            yield s"$x$y"
```

(returns an iterator, so force its evaluation)

```
res.toList //> res1: List[String] = List(ab, ac, ad, bc, bd, cd)
```

which suggests yet another variant, from desugaring

```
a.tails.collect{case(x::xs) => xs.map(y=>s"$x$y")}.flatten.toList
//> res2: List[String] = List(ab, ac, ad, bc, bd, cd)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is very comprehensive. I'm very new to Scala so which approach is more Scala-ian? Recursive or comprehension?

Comment: Either. Don't think there's much to choose between them

Comment: I think `tails` is a natural fit for this problem.

Comment: I ended up using the comprehension with tails. It did exactly what I needed it to do while being easy to read.

Answer (score 2):

Remembering that in Scala what we have is a 'for-comprehension' rather than a 'for-loop' in the Java sense, the construction isn't "nested" in the same sense as it would be in Java. Specifically, it would look something like:

```
// For a list of items of some type 'A':
val items: List[A] = ???

// and some suitable combining function (which might be inlined if simple enough):
def fn(i1: A, i2: A): A = ???

// an example for-comprehension that will achieve the output you describe:
for {
  x <- items.zipWithIndex
  y <- items.zipWithIndex
  z <- List(fn(x._1, y._1)) if (x._2 < y._2) 
} yield z
```

which seems clean enough to me. This de-sugars to something like:

```
items.zipWithIndex.flatMap( x => 
  items.zipWithIndex.flatMap( y => 
    List(fn(x._1, y._1)).withFilter( z => x._2 < y._2 ).map( z => z ) ) )
```

which while being much more along the lines of the "List comprehension" you specifically asked for, seems less clear to read to me!

Answer (score 1):

If you are combining Strings you could do something like this.

```
scala> List("a","b","c","d").combinations(2).map(s => s.head+s.last).toList
res5: List[String] = List(ab, ac, ad, bc, bd, cd)
```

But you refer to it as "a way to apply each element" so maybe you mean something else?  If so, perhaps this approach could get you started.

Comment: I had forgotten about the `combinations` method - good pickup. Slight word of warning, however, you may not get quite the result you expected if any of the elements in the list are identical. Also, you can swap out your inlined function `s => s.head + s.last` for `s => fn(s.head, s.last)` where `fn` is any other function combining two strings (or more generally any other type if dealing with lists of other types) you have available.

Comment: Good point.  The OP's example appears to rule out duplicates but, yes, if duplicate values are allowed then `combinations()` won't get you where you want to go.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Duplicates are not allowed and I should have stated in my question that the "application" can be any arbitrary function, not necessarily a concatenation.